# How can I count rows into more than one 'then' of a Postgres searched case expression? (reporting)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, report, case

**Background**

I have a Postgres 11 database running on RDS.  I need to produce a report which shows counts of events over a certain period, grouping, renaming, and counting them based on description strings into categories according to business requirements.

**Problem**
For this sort of thing, I typically go for a searched case expression, which is working well *except*: 
Part of the spec requires *some* events must be counted into more than one category.  But when the case expression is evaluated, it counts [or appears to count] each row into only one category [the first matching one in the expression].

Example:

```
     SELECT 
          CASE 
            WHEN (some_table.description ILIKE '%foo%' OR some_table.description ILIKE ‘%foobar%') THEN 'foo' 
            WHEN (some_table.description ILIKE '%bar%' OR some_table.description ILIKE ‘%foobar%) THEN 'bar'
          END AS ‘category’,
          count(*)
    FROM some_table 
    GROUP BY category
    ORDER BY category DESC
    ;
```

So, given data like

```
event_id         |   description
---------------------------------
1                |    ‘string including foo’
2                |   ‘foo also included in this string’
3                |   ‘ this string includes bar’
4                |   ‘this one says foobar’
```

output expected is like so:

```
some_table
category         |      count
---------------------------------
foo              |    3
bar              |    2
```

However, the actual output is being returned as

```
some_table
category         |      count
---------------------------------
foo              |    3
bar              |    1
```

How can I get records with description containing ‘foobar’ to be counted into both ‘foo’ and ‘bar’ categories?  And if a case expression is the wrong method for this reporting goal, what should be used?  All guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output stops at the first match.  If you want both, use a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.category, COUNT(*)
FROM some_table t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN s.description ILIKE '%foo%' OR s.description ILIKE '%foobar%' THEN 'foo' END),
             (CASE WHEN s.description ILIKE '%bar%' OR s.description ILIKE '%foobar% THEN 'bar' END)
     ) v(category)
WHERE v.category IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY v.category
ORDER BY v.category DESC
;
```

Comment: Fantastic! Tremendously useful solution and a new-to-me way to employ case expressions.  Thanks much!